# Issue with Integer values associated with Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory

thanks for your time!

First note:  For all primes p greater than 3, p does not divide 6 and p and 6 are coprime. So, by Fermat's Little Theorem, we have:
$6^{(p-1)} \equiv 1 \ (mod \ p)$
and so $6^{(p-1)} \equiv p+1 \ (mod \ p)$.
Since p and 6 are coprime, $6^{(p-2)} \equiv \frac{p+1}{6}\ (mod \ p)$.

The issue is that this should not depend on the form of p.  However, if p=6n-1 for some n $\in$ Naturals, then $\frac{p+1}{6}$ is a natural, and there's no issue.  If, on the other hand, p=6n+1, then $\frac{p+1}{6}$ is not a natural!!!

By observation I find that, instead, if p=6n+1, then $6^{(p-2)} \equiv -\lfloor\frac{p+1}{6} \rfloor\ (mod \ p)$.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Without proper formatting, this is almost unreadable.  However, I think you are misinterpreting the $\frac 16$.  Think of it as multiplying by $6^{-1}$...where this means the multiplicative inverse of $6\pmod p$.  Thus, $6^{-1}\equiv 6 \pmod 7$, say, as $6\times 6\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Comment: The edit is a big improvement.  As in my prior comment, $6^{p-1}\equiv 1\implies 6^{p-2}\equiv 6^{-1}$ (all congruences $\pmod p$).  If $p=6n+1$ then $6^{-1}\equiv -n$ as $-6n=1-p\equiv 1$ and, of course, $n=\lfloor \frac {p+1}6\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks,  that's right. I think I got it... If p=6n+1, then $6^{p-1} \equiv 1 \ (mod \ p)$ implies $6^{p-1} \equiv 1-p \ (mod \ p)$, so $6^{p-1} \equiv -(p-1) \ (mod \ p)$, and we have $6^{p-2} \equiv -\frac{p-1}{6} \ (mod \ p)$ where $\frac{p-1}{6}=n=\lfloor \frac{p+1}{6} \rfloor$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ \gcd(n,6)=1\,$ then either $\ n\, =\,\underbrace{ 6k-1}_{\Large 6\color{#c00}k\,\equiv\, 1\,}\ $ or $\!\underbrace{6k+1}_{\Large 6(\color{#0a0}{-k})\,\equiv\, 1}\! $ so $\,\ 6^{-1} \equiv\color{#c00} k\,$ or $\, \color{#0a0}{-k}\pmod n$